# How to pass React props from parent to child using composition pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, composition

As stated [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context), a good way to pass properties to child component is via composition pattern. My problem is that I need to pass props from several component to the same child, with the maximum de-couplication:

```
export default function App() {
  const foo = true;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent>
        <Child foo={foo} />
      </Parent>
    </div>
  );
}

function Parent(props) {
  function methodA() {
    return true;
  }

  // return <div>I'm the parent! {props.children(methodA)}</div>; // <-- gives me error!
  return <div>I'm the parent! {props.children}</div>;
}

function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      I'm the child!
      <br />
      App pass me foo: {props.foo.toString()}
      <br />
      Parent pass methodA: {/*props.methodA().toString()<-- gives me error!*/}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-forest-igfyl?file=/src/App.js)

As you can see, I've got no problem to pass values from my top one to the lowest, or from the middle one to the lower,  but I cannot achieve a way to do both the same time, using the `children` props to keep thing de-coupled.

Is that possible in some way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the above pattern can strictly be called `composition`. The way I see it, composition would involve `App` passing `Child` as props to the `Parent` component and `Parent` does not modify `Child` in any way. But that might be a technicality.

Anyway, the problem here seems to be that you cannot pass `methodA` to the `Child` component. One way to solve this is to clone the `Child` element in the `Parent` component and add your props to it. So, your new `Parent` component would look something like:

```
function Parent(props) {
  function methodA() {
    return true;
  }
  const NewChild = React.cloneElement(props.children);
  return <div>I'm the parent! <NewChild methodA={methodA} /></div>;
}
```

You can read more about `cloneElement` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).

Answer (score 0):

From the [ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance):

> Remember that components may accept arbitrary props, including primitive values, React elements, or functions.

You could make `Parent`'s `children` prop a function.

```
export default function App() {
  const foo = true;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent>{(methodA) => <Child foo={foo} methodA={methodA} />}</Parent>
    </div>
  );
}

function Parent(props) {
  function methodA() {
    return true;
  }

  return <div>I'm the parent! {props.children(methodA)}</div>;
}

function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      I'm the child!
      <br />
      App pass me foo: {props.foo.toString()}
      <br />
      Parent pass methodA: {props.methodA().toString()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-northcutt-2om3o?file=/src/App.js